# Converting an existing app to react produces unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm new to React.  I have an existing traditional web app (uses jquery) that I would like to convert to React, but am getting an error in the browser. I have used create-react-app to create a new React project.  In index.html, I added my html under the

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

My ./src/index.js is the standard:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

My App.js is the standard:
import React, {Component} from 'react'

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

When I run it with "npm start", the "Hello World" is displayed, followed by my existing html.  But that page shows the existing html with none of the javascript functionality behind it.  The index.html contains a link to the existing javascript, like this:

```
<script src="../src/components/SplitPane/SplitPane.js"></script>
```

That javascript starts with jquery like this:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.splitPane = function() {
    var $splitPanes = this;
    $splitPanes.each(setMinHeightAndMinWidth);
```

In the Chrome console, I see the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (on line 1 of SplitPane.js)

That line doesn't even have any '<' or '>' tokens so the error doesn't make sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing the closing angle bracket on the opening div#root tag.

Comment: Sorry, I just typed in in wrong on this post.  I've updated the post.

Comment: So you included a React hello world app on your old app? Are you expecting it to suddenly become a react app? Because that's not possible, sorry.

Comment: No.  I want to gradually convert an existing app to React one step at a time.  This is just the first step in the process. I haven't changed any of the existing javascript yet.  Why does React prevent it from being invoked?

Comment: You might want to separate the hello world from the old app, and slowly begin moving bits into the new app. And the error message is pretty clear: there's a missing ">" somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like splitpane isn't loading correctly (since "<" is the first character of a 404 response).

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code for HTML, `>` is missing.